# Browser issues with VPN

Tags: linux, routing, vpn, browser

I have a VPN setup which usually works completely fine. However, when I connect to my VPN server via some wifis, Firefox and Chrome seem to run into issues and aren't able to open websites anymore. So far I watched this misbehaviour only in wifis with 10.x.y.z internal IPs, but that may be a coincidence. Anything from commandline, curl, wget and friends have no problem to connect through the VPN, the same with e.g. Thunderbird. Though, Chrome and Firefox both can't open any website.

Both browsers seem to wait an eternity for some response, not giving any quick error message. Also, right after connection to the VPN, opening 1-2 websites may work sometimes, before the connection freezes. Any idea, what's going wrong here?

```
# netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.10.10.5      0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 tun0
0.0.0.0         10.20.113.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlan0
10.10.10.5      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 tun0
10.10.10.5      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 tun0
10.10.10.6      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 tun0
10.20.113.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan0
_vpnhost_       10.20.113.1     255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 wlan0
```

There are no firewall settings forbidding any traffic:

```
# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

And it even looks like, that firefox actually manages to connect (heise.de):

```
# lsof -i -a -p 27648
COMMAND   PID    USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
firefox 27648 michael   61u  IPv4 878646      0t0  TCP 10.10.10.6:53372->ec2-54-186-218-125.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 27648 michael   65u  IPv4 878643      0t0  TCP 10.10.10.6:47076->ec2-54-191-113-255.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 27648 michael   66u  IPv4 878689      0t0  TCP 10.10.10.6:41718->www.heise.de:http (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 27648 michael   68u  IPv4 878669      0t0  TCP 10.10.10.6:52994->server-54-230-79-235.cdg50.r.cloudfront.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
```

This is the log of the initiation sequence:

```
Mar 26 09:35:51 nyx nm-openvpn[19187]: OpenVPN 2.3.7 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Jul  8 2015
Mar 26 09:35:51 nyx nm-openvpn[19187]: library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015, LZO 2.08
Mar 26 09:35:51 nyx nm-openvpn[19187]: NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
Mar 26 09:35:51 nyx nm-openvpn[19187]: Control Channel Authentication: using '.../ta.key' as a OpenVPN static key file
Mar 26 09:35:51 nyx nm-openvpn[19187]: UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Mar 26 09:35:51 nyx nm-openvpn[19187]: UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]_vpnhost_:1194
Mar 26 09:35:53 nyx nm-openvpn[19187]: [tritone] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]144.76.64.108:1194
Mar 26 09:35:55 nyx nm-openvpn[19187]: TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Mar 26 09:35:55 nyx nm-openvpn[19187]: /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-openvpn-service-openvpn-helper --tun -- tun0 1500 1602 10.10.10.6 10.10.10.5 init
Mar 26 09:35:55 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:   (tun0): new Tun device (carrier: OFF, driver: 'tun', ifindex: 12)
Mar 26 09:35:55 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:   VPN connection 'Novocalculus' (IP Config Get) reply received.
Mar 26 09:35:55 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:   devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0)
Mar 26 09:35:55 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:   device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Mar 26 09:35:55 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:   VPN connection 'Novocalculus' (IP4 Config Get) reply received.
Mar 26 09:35:55 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:   VPN Gateway: 144.76.64.108
Mar 26 09:35:55 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:   Tunnel Device: tun0
Mar 26 09:35:55 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:   IPv4 configuration:
Mar 26 09:35:55 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:     Internal Gateway: 10.10.10.5
Mar 26 09:35:55 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:     Internal Address: 10.10.10.6
Mar 26 09:35:55 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:     Internal Prefix: 32
Mar 26 09:35:55 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:     Internal Point-to-Point Address: 10.10.10.5
Mar 26 09:35:55 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:     Maximum Segment Size (MSS): 0
Mar 26 09:35:55 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:     Forbid Default Route: no
Mar 26 09:35:55 nyx nm-openvpn[19187]: Initialization Sequence Completed
Mar 26 09:35:55 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:     Internal DNS: 10.10.10.1
Mar 26 09:35:55 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:     DNS Domain: '(none)'
Mar 26 09:35:55 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:   No IPv6 configuration
Mar 26 09:35:55 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:   VPN plugin state changed: started (4)
Mar 26 09:35:55 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:   VPN connection 'Novocalculus' (IP Config Get) complete.
Mar 26 09:35:55 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:   (tun0): link connected
Mar 26 09:35:55 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:   NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Mar 26 09:35:55 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:   NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Mar 26 09:35:55 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:   Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Mar 26 09:35:55 nyx dnsmasq[1184]: vorgelagerte Server von DBus gesetzt
Mar 26 09:35:55 nyx dnsmasq[1184]: Benutze Namensserver 10.10.10.1#53
```

Another observation: If I use HMA instead of my own VPN, it works without problems. HMA seems to be configured differently. It includes IPv6 and does not use point-to-point? only. For reference here the login sequence to HMA:

```
Mar 26 09:24:35 nyx nm-openvpn[17575]: OpenVPN 2.3.7 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Jul  8 2015
Mar 26 09:24:35 nyx nm-openvpn[17575]: library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015, LZO 2.08
Mar 26 09:24:35 nyx nm-openvpn[17575]: NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
Mar 26 09:24:35 nyx nm-openvpn[17575]: Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]_hmahost_:443 [nonblock]
Mar 26 09:24:36 nyx nm-openvpn[17575]: TCP connection established with [AF_INET]_hmahost_:443
Mar 26 09:24:36 nyx nm-openvpn[17575]: TCPv4_CLIENT link local: [undef]
Mar 26 09:24:36 nyx nm-openvpn[17575]: TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]_hmahost_:443
Mar 26 09:24:40 nyx nm-openvpn[17575]: [server] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]_hmahost_:443
Mar 26 09:24:43 nyx nm-openvpn[17575]: Option 'explicit-exit-notify' in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:7 is ignored by previous  blocks
Mar 26 09:24:43 nyx nm-openvpn[17575]: TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Mar 26 09:24:43 nyx nm-openvpn[17575]: /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-openvpn-service-openvpn-helper --tun -- tun0 1500 1543 10.200.2.126 255.255.252.0 init
Mar 26 09:24:43 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:   (tun0): new Tun device (carrier: OFF, driver: 'tun', ifindex: 11)
Mar 26 09:24:43 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:   devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0)
Mar 26 09:24:43 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:   device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Mar 26 09:24:43 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:   VPN connection 'HMA UK' (IP Config Get) reply received.
Mar 26 09:24:43 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:   VPN connection 'HMA UK' (IP4 Config Get) reply received.
Mar 26 09:24:43 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:   VPN connection 'HMA UK' (IP6 Config Get) reply received.
Mar 26 09:24:43 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:   VPN Gateway: 109.169.94.53
Mar 26 09:24:43 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:   Tunnel Device: tun0
Mar 26 09:24:43 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:   IPv4 configuration:
Mar 26 09:24:43 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:     Internal Gateway: 10.200.0.1
Mar 26 09:24:43 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:     Internal Address: 10.200.2.126
Mar 26 09:24:43 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:     Internal Prefix: 22
Mar 26 09:24:43 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:     Internal Point-to-Point Address: 0.0.0.0
Mar 26 09:24:43 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:     Maximum Segment Size (MSS): 0
Mar 26 09:24:43 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:     Forbid Default Route: no
Mar 26 09:24:43 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:     Internal DNS: 10.200.0.1
Mar 26 09:24:43 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:     DNS Domain: '(none)'
Mar 26 09:24:43 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:   IPv6 configuration:
Mar 26 09:24:43 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:     Internal Address: 2001:db8:123::2
Mar 26 09:24:43 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:     Internal Prefix: 64
Mar 26 09:24:43 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:     Internal Point-to-Point Address: 2001:db8:123::1
Mar 26 09:24:43 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:     Maximum Segment Size (MSS): 0
Mar 26 09:24:43 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:     Static Route: 2000::/3   Next Hop: 2001:db8:123::1
Mar 26 09:24:43 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:     Forbid Default Route: no
Mar 26 09:24:43 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:     DNS Domain: '(none)'
Mar 26 09:24:43 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:   VPN plugin state changed: started (4)
Mar 26 09:24:43 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:   VPN connection 'HMA UK' (IP Config Get) complete.
Mar 26 09:24:43 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:   (tun0): link connected
Mar 26 09:24:43 nyx nm-openvpn[17575]: Initialization Sequence Completed
Mar 26 09:24:43 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:   NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Mar 26 09:24:43 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:   NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Mar 26 09:24:43 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:   Policy set 'HMA UK' (tun0) as default for IPv6 routing and DNS.
Mar 26 09:24:43 nyx NetworkManager[25408]:   Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Mar 26 09:24:43 nyx dnsmasq[1184]: vorgelagerte Server von DBus gesetzt
Mar 26 09:24:43 nyx dnsmasq[1184]: Benutze Namensserver 10.200.0.1#53 für Domain 10.in-addr.arpa
```

Comment: What happens if you try [`http://193.99.144.80`](http://193.99.144.80)? Did you completely exit/restart Firefox and Chrome after connection?

Comment: Restarting the browser doesn't help, also directly accessing the IP, so the IP resolution isn't the problem. Though, the only difference with feeding in the IP directly is, that Chrome right away complained about waiting for free sockets. A lack of sockets may actually explain the strange behaviour, though, I got no idea where this shortage should come from.

Comment: IP resolution? Do you mean routing with that? It looks like your DNS resolution is blocked, or times out. Have you looked at the nameserver you use when working via VPN?

Comment: I meant DNS lookup. And as I said, typing in the IP directly, bypassing any need for DNS lookup, is of no help. So the DNS is imho not to blame.